# Animate 'Style' property of Control using ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames in WPF

Tags: wpf, controls, styles, animated

I am trying to animate 'Style' property using ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames. When I run the sample below, I just see empty window and there are no any exceptions.

Almost the same sample works in Silverlight. In WPF it works too, if I assign 'Style' property of the control directly. Does anyone know if it is possible to animate 'Style' property in WPF?

Many thanks.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:this="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    >
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <Style x:Key="TestStyle" TargetType="Control">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Canvas x:Name="Rectangle">
                            <Rectangle Width="200" Height="150" Fill="Red"/>
                        </Canvas>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Target" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style" >
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TestStyle}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Canvas.Triggers>

    <Canvas.Children>
        <ContentControl x:Name="Target"/>
    </Canvas.Children>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: try DynamicResource instead of StaticResource.

Answer (score 1):

When `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` tries to animate to a value that is derived from `DependencyObject`, it attempts to [freeze](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509.aspx) the object first. If the object can't be frozen, it throws an exception and the animation does not run.

If you are animating a value of a custom type that you wrote, it appears you need to either derive from `Freezable` or NOT derive from `DependencyObject`.

For properties that already exist that derive from `DependencyObject` and not `Freezable`, you can't animate them (`StyleProperty` or `TemplateProperty` are cases in point). Try using a property setter inside of a style:

```
<Style.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource TestTemplate}"/>
  </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Build all of the transition logic into the style instead of switching between different styles. A challenge that you may have with this is that the target property has to be a dependency property so you can't use `IsLoaded`.

I hope you find this useful.

One final thought: It is possible to define [custom animations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970564.aspx), although I have not done this myself. There's an outside chance that you could write your own custom "ObjectAnimation" that would not be restricted to `Freezable` or non-`DependencyObject` classes.

Comment: If you give more information about why you wanted to animate a style I may be able to suggest other alternatives. Although it may seem nice to animate to a different style, I'm sure there are other ways to achieve the desired effect.